# Rotate image with mouse in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mouse

I have a gif animation showing a rotating object:
[Rotating gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KcqT.jpg)

I want the user to be able to control the rotation with the mouse.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easly with gsap graddable if you want your users grab the image for rotate. See this link https://greensock.com/draggable/

Look this for rotate on mouse move: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16506-rotate-on-mouse/